# Rookie: How do I list accounts I've created

Tags: go-ethereum

I am new to Etherium, using Ubuntu CLI ,I was wondering how to properly manage accounts. I am trying to simply list the accounts I've created using the following syntax:

> geth account list

Found at the following resource: 
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts
But the CLI returns the following info:

> INFO [03-28|08:58:21] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25

How do I return a list of accounts I've created? Better yet, a list of accounts and status (locked or unlocked)?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4159/16048

Comment: Before flagging duplicates, please understand the content of both posts. The question you refer to is regarding unlocking an account. My question is with regard to listing accounts that have been created. Yes, it would be nice to display the account status in the list, but not necessary.

Comment: I was doubtful, that's why "possible" duplicate :P But now I understand, its not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach to your running geth process either by running in your current directory (where `geth.ipc` exists)

```
geth attach ./geth.ipc
```

Or running on the same machine

```
geth attach http://localhost:8545
```

And you will be presented with a console. Run in the console `eth.accounts` and your accounts should be listed

```
> eth.accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the method proposed by @cleanunicorn, you can also do:

```
geth --datadir $HOME/path/to/datadir account list
```

Make sure to set `datadir` to the same folder where `geth` is running and your `keystore` is located.