# Using Coinbase ETH Wallet to save contracts/send transactions with web3

Tags: web3js, transactions, contract-deployment, coinbase

I am working on a node app where I am using web3, Infura & [truffle-hdwallet-provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-hdwallet-provider) & a new MetaMask wallet. This process appears to work & I can successfully deploy contracts!

I want to know if it is possible to deploy contracts & send transactions with a Coinbase ETH account (instead of my new MetaMask one)?

The `truffle-hdwallet-provider` package requires a mnemonic to authorise the wallet, but, is this possible with a coinbase account I cannot seem to see this or a private key in my dashboard?

One post I have found touches upon this where they suggest it's possible if I "unlock" the account using a password, which is insecure if using a `http` "provider"
[Judging from the warnings regarding unlocking accounts, I think I should avoid this method](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/how-to-unlock-the-account-with-geth)
If I was to simply use a https provider, would this be suitable or still insecure & undesirable for production?

If I were to use this method, would the password for my Coinbase ETH Wallet simply be my account password?

I appreciate I have asked a few questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to make a clear distinction between the centralised Coinbase Ether wallet and their recent Ethereum-native wallet called Coinbase Wallet (previously Toshi).

### [Coinbase Ether](https://coinbase.com)

You'll never ever be able to deploy anything from Coinbase's dashboard wallet. It is a **centralised** app, using traditional web technologies and it's most likely [secured](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/topics/794360-security/articles) by a multisignature wallet owned by Coinbase's shareholders and trusted members.

### [Coinbase Wallet](https://wallet.coinbase.com)

You can do whatever you want because this is a different product, a wallet for Ethereum **decentralised** apps. You can create a new HD wallet and a new mnemonic will be generated for you. Just copy and paste that securely in a `.env` file. You can install [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to safely manage the variables if you're using node.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Paul,I presumed it wouldn't be possible. Thanks for pointing out Coinbase Wallet, never even knew about it looks suitable.