# web3.eth.getAccounts() yields an empty array

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, mac-osx

I first  started geth:  `geth --syncmode "light" --rpc --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir ~/eth_blocks/` and then used: `geth account new`.

I verified that there is a new entry in `~/Library/Ethereum/keystore/`.

Then when i run this code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3')
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545/'))
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

It logs an empty array: `[]`

Why is it not outputting what is in the keystore?

Comment: You should probably get those accounts unlocked (on the node side).

Comment: Here's a [related question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4157/how-to-unlock-the-account-with-geth) with more info on unlocking your geth accounts.